# siunitx inputting multiple dimensions

Tags: siunitx

i have a quick question that I can't seem to find the asnwer to, and it concerns the package siunitx. See the following example...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI{330x10}{mm}
\end{document}
```

In overleaf, this will display it as shown
[image]

However, when I run the same thing on my system (Miktex and VScode) is absolutely breaks. So I was wondering, is there a proper way to input 2 dimensions into a \SI{}{} command? or do I just have to split them into  \SI{}{} x \SI{}{} to make it work.

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the changes between v2 and v3 is that products now have a dedicated interface, but that means they are not allowed in a 'single' quantity. Probably the best approach if you need to work with v2 and v3 for the same source is to provide the v3 name if v2 is detected

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ifdefined\qtyproduct
\else
  \ifdefined\NewCommandCopy
    \NewCommandCopy\qtyproduct\SI
  \else
    \NewDocumentCommand\qtyproduct{O{}mm}{\SI[#1]{#2}{#3}}
  \fi
\fi
\begin{document}
\qtyproduct{330x10}{mm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, in v3 the commands have been given different names to make their function more obvious, so from now on i would use \qty{}{} instead of \SI{}{} right? and then use \qtyproduct for this use case

Comment: @RubendeV Yes, I've tried to improve the naming. Notice that `\SI` and `\si` are still there in v3, and I have no plans to remove them - for most people, older documents will just work, but for products and complex numbers I felt `\SI` and `\num` were too overloaded with syntax.